# Awk how to negate a condition

Tags: awk

I'm trying to compute some stuff in awk, and at the end print the result in the order of the input. For each line, I check if it has not been already seen. If not, I add it to the array and also store it in an `order` array.

```
{
    if (! $0 in seen) {
        seen[$0] = 1
        order[o++] = $0
    }
} END {
    for (i=0; i<o; i++)
        printf "%s\n", order[i]
}
```

You can try it with

```
printf 'a\nb\na\nc\nb\na\n' | awk script_above
```

It prints nothing. If I print the variable `o` at the end, it shows that its value is still 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `(! $0 in seen) ` to `(! ( $0 in seen )) `.  It's just an operator precedence issue.

Comment: HA! It works! Initially I wanted to ask "what is the literal syntax to negate a condition" because the questions/answers I found always answered something else, but I thought "ok let's be humble and assume my code is generally wrong...". Well I was right, my condition was the weak spot. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add parens to get the right operator precedence*:

```
# a.awk

{
    if (!($0 in seen)) {
        seen[$0] = 1
        order[o++] = $0
    }
}

END {
    for (i=0; i<o; i++)
        printf "%s\n", order[i]
}
```

Test:

```
$ awk -f a.awk file
a
b
c
```

* (The unary `!` binds more tightly than the `in` operator: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Precedence.html)

Comment: More awkishly: `!seen[$0]++{order[++o]=$0} END{for (i=1; i<=o; i++) print order[i]}'`

Comment: @Ed Morton Although it's more awkish, it did not work for my complete use-case. It triggered syntax errors I couldn't solve, and errored on special characters (`\035`: group separator).

Comment: There is no way that produced syntax errors and there are no "special characters" in the code nor would it care about any characters at all in the input. Hang on - did you leave that `'` at the end in your code? Surely you can see that's just a typo in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is in Shell way, `awk` has a way where you could keep checking if an element is part of an array or not, try following once.

```
printf 'a\nb\na\nc\nb\na\n' | awk '
    !seen[$0]++ {
        order[o++] = $0
    }
END {
    for (i=0; i<o; i++)
        printf "%s\n", order[i]
}'
```

Here `!seen[$0]++` means it is checking condition if an element is NOT a part of indexes of array named `a` then go inside the BLOCK(where your next statements are provided) then it does `++` which makes sure that this element(which was NOT there in array before checking condition)'s counter incremented by 1 so that next time this !seen[$0]++` condition is NOT TRUE for the already passed element.

Comment: @pawamoy, could you please check this above solution once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you for the explanation :) This solution is elegant but a bit more complicated than the original code. I'm goind to pick the other answer as accepted because it really points where I struggled: how to negate a condition.

Comment: @pawamoy, your welcome, sure; will be happy if you select any of the answer :) cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Just a question: would it be better if I changed the title to reflect it (how to negate a condition)? Because the current title was just something I picked as a use-case. Since I didn't find the answer on StackOverflow, changing the title might help the next ones?

Comment: @pawamoy, sure you could do so, we have to have a good question so that it can  help others in future, feel free to edit it as per your thoughts, cheers.

Comment: This is the right way to use a `seen[]` array but while that `order[]` code will function, traditionally awk arrays start at 1, not zero so that code should be `order[++o] = $0` and then `for (i=1; i<0o; i++)`

Comment: It seems I cannot use this syntax in a `{}` block before `END` (I get syntax errors). It also seems to badly handle special characters (`unexpected character 0x1b`).

Comment: @pawamoy, not sure which o.s you are there, for me it worked fine.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my awk is `mawk 1.3.3`, I'm on Bunsenlabs (it's based on Debian 9). I tried it with `gawk` and `original-awk`, same syntax errors. Your code as itself works fine, it's when I enclose the first part in curly brackets that it errors: `{ seen { order } } END { print }`, and I need these brackets because I compute other things at the same time :) Anyway, I'm certainly not knowlegeable enough in Awk, there are obviously things I don't understand, so I'll stop here as it goes out of scope of the question! Thank you again.